# Android Studio Toolbar İs Not Showing

Tags: java, menu, toolbar

Android Studio Toolbar İs Not Showing

Hello Guys,
I am sure that my codes for creating the menu in Android Studio are correct, and it also does not give an error, but when I run my project, the menu does not appear on the page.
[İmage1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2apy.png)
[İmage2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iz1g0.png)

Answer (score 0):

open project panel
app -> src -> main -> res -> values -> themes.xml

when opeing themes

in line three delete noActionBar

```
parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar"
```

it should be like this

```
parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight"
```

hope it helps.